# $\mathbb{R}/{\sim}$ is compact for $x\sim y$ if $x=2^n y$

Tags: general-topology, compactness

Let $\mathbb{R}$ with the standard topology and endow equivalence relation $x \sim y$ if $x=2^n y$ for $n \in \mathbb{Z}$.

I want to show $\mathbb{R}/ \sim $ is a compact space, and further for $\mathbb{R}^{+} = \{x \in\mathbb{R}\mid x>0\}$, $\mathbb{R}^+ / {\sim}$ is homeomoprhic to the unit circle $S^1$.

---

First I know $\mathbb{R}$ is not compact and $S^1$ is compact.  To show $\mathbb{R}/{\sim}$ is compact, I have to show its open cover has a finite subcover.  But I am not sure how this equivalence relation provides finite subcover.

Comment: You would have to know what the open sets of $\mathbb R / \sim$ are. Do you know a characterization of these, in terms of the open sets in $\mathbb R$? It involves the quotient topology. So what you'll need to do is consider an open cover of $\mathbb R$, pull these back to open sets on $\mathbb R$, choose some finite number of those open sets in $\mathbb R$ and push them back. We can help you with the choosing, but the pulling and pushing of these sets across the quotient map must first be clear for you.

Comment: Actually, the argument for the first part is extremely similar to what has been done [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3737438/characterization-of-a-quotient-space-of-mathbbr2?noredirect=1). In particular, following pull-backs, you pretty much note that every equivalence class has members arbitrarily close to $0$ and then consider any open set containing the equivalence class $[0]$ and what happens it if is pulled back.

Comment: Let $\pi : \Bbb R \to \Bbb R/{\sim}$ be the standard projection. If I understand correctly, any open set of $\Bbb R/{\sim}$ containing $\pi(0)$ must necessarily be the whole space. The intuition here is that an open set containing $\pi(0)$ is of the form $\pi[U]$ where $U \subset \Bbb R$ is open. Now, given any $x \in \Bbb R$, you can find $N$ large enough so that $2^{-N} x \in U$. Thus, $\pi(x) = \pi(2^{-N} x) \in \pi[U]$. --- So not only does every cover have a finite subcover, it actually has a cover of size $1$.

Comment: Also, if you are a follower of Bourbaki, then the space is only quasi-compact as it is not Hausdorff ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$\newcommand{\R}{\Bbb R}\newcommand{\RR}{\Bbb R/{\sim}}$ Let $\pi : \R \to \RR$ be the standard projection map.

---

For the first part, here's a sketch: Given any open set $U \subset \Bbb R$ containing $0$ and any $x \in \Bbb R$, we can choose $N \in \Bbb Z^+$ large enough such that $2^{-N}x \in U$.
Thus, $\pi(x) = \pi(2^{-N}x) \in \pi[U]$ for any $x \in \R$ and any open neighbourhood of $0$.

From this, conclude that the only open neighbourhood of $\pi(0)$ is $\RR$. In turn, every cover actually has a singleton subcover!

---

For the second part: Consider the map $$f : \R^+ \to S^1$$ defined as $$x \mapsto \exp(2 \pi \iota \log_2(x)).$$
Here $\iota$ denotes the imaginary unit and I consider $S^1$ as a subspace of $\Bbb C$ in the standard way.
It is easy to see that $f$ is onto. (Use the fact that $\log_2 : \R^+ \to \R$ is onto.)

For $x, y \in \R^+$, note the following
\begin{align}
f(x) = f(y) &\iff \exp(2 \pi \iota (\log_2(x) - \log_2(y)) = 1 \\
& \iff \log_2(x) - \log_2(y) \in \Bbb Z \\
& \iff x \sim y.
\end{align}

Thus, $f$ induces a continuous bijection $\tilde f : \R^+/{\sim} \to S^1$. (This is a fact about quotient spaces. For example, see Corollary 22.3. from Munkres.)

Now, to show that $\tilde f$ is a homeomorphism, it suffices to show that $f$ is a quotient map (again, the same Corollary from Munkres).

But this follows because $f$ can be seen to be a composition of the following maps:

$$\R^+ \xrightarrow{\log_2} \R \xrightarrow{x \mapsto \exp(2\pi\iota x)} S^1.$$

The first map is a homeomorphism (and hence, a quotient map) and the second is a quotient map. (This is a standard fact, you might want to prove it if you have not.)

Thus, being the composition of quotient maps, $f$ is also a quotient map and thus, $\tilde f$ is a homeomorphism.

Comment: Does Munkres Corollary work like homomorphism theorem in algebra: $f:A\to B$ is onto, then $A/\ker f\cong B$? Is the openness of $\tilde{f}$ encoded in the term "quotient map" somehow?

Comment: @AlvinLepik: Between you and me, that's how I interpret it but looking up "first isomorphism theorem in topology" does not really turn up anything. In the case of algebra, a bijective homomorphism is sufficient to be an iso but here, we need the extra condition about "quotient map" to ensure that the bijective continuous map that we get is actually a homeo (i.e., is open).